# PowerShell - List WSUS Updates Needed for Each Client

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting, windows-update, wsus

I need to provide a monthly report to our client listing the **updates needed by each Windows server in our environment**. Ideally, the report would list the u**pdates for the month and the servers in my environment that need them**.

My PowerShell knowledge is limited but I found some scripts (see below) and tweaked them a bit to pull the updates and the targets, but I can't figure out a way to **combine this information** into one script that shows the **specific updates are needed by each server**:

```
$wsus = Get-WsusServer -Name "<server-name>" -PortNumber 8530

$wsus.GetComputerTargets()

$updates = $wsus.GetUpdates() | where {$_.CreationDate -gt (Get-Date).addMonths(-1) }

# Iterate through every update, output some info

$results = ForEach ($update in $updates) {

$update.Title

$update.Description

$update.CreationDate

}

$results | Out-File C:\Temp\results.txt

## Select all WSUS clients export to file

$serverlist = ForEach ($server in $wsus.GetComputerTargets()) {

$server.FullDomainName
$server.OSDescription
}

$serverlist | Out-File C:\Temp\servers.txt
```

Any suggestions or advice would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I spent some time looking, the options are awful, surely MS need to sort this out.

I have used the below which is lengthy, copy all to use including the blocks to the "endregion send email":

Credit to https://github.com/proxb/WSUSReport/blob/master/WSUSReport.ps1 for the main script, I had challenges to get the server updated needed count included.

I added to line 275 or after Sort Computername in "#Failed Installations" Section:

```perl
#Needed Count
$computerscope = New-Object Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.ComputerTargetScope
$updatescope = New-Object Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.UpdateScope
$GroupNeededHash=@{}
$ComputerUpdatesNeeded = $wsus.GetSummariesPerComputerTarget($updatescope,$computerscope) | Select @{L='ComputerTarget';E={($wsus.GetComputerTarget([guid]$_.ComputerTargetId)).FullDomainName}}, `
@{L='NeededCount';E={($_.DownloadedCount + $_.NotInstalledCount)}} | Where-Object { $_.NeededCount -ne '0' }| Sort NeededCount -Descending | ForEach {
}
```

and then to line 538 or after "#endregion Failed Update Install":

```perl
    #region Needed Update Install
    $Pre = @"
        <div style='margin: 0px auto; BACKGROUND-COLOR:RED;Color:Black;font-weight:bold;FONT-SIZE: 14pt;'>
            Needed Update Installations By Computer
        </div>

"@
    $Body = $wsus.GetSummariesPerComputerTarget($updatescope,$computerscope) | Select @{L='ComputerTarget';E={($wsus.GetComputerTarget([guid]$_.ComputerTargetId)).FullDomainName}}, `
    @{L='NeededCount';E={($_.DownloadedCount + $_.NotInstalledCount)}} | Where-Object { $_.NeededCount -gt '4' }| Sort NeededCount -Descending | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment | Out-String | Set-AlternatingCSSClass -CSSEvenClass 'even' -CssOddClass 'odd'

    $Post = "<br>"
    $htmlFragment += $Pre,$Body,$Post
    #endregion Needed Update Install
```